# SXSSFWorkbook Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already

Tags: java, apache-poi, sxssf

I'm getting an exception while writing data into an SXSSFWorkbook file. I could do the same using XSSFWorkbook and it worked just fine.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:230)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.write(SXSSFWorkbook.java:953)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:79)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:61)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
```

Here is my code.

```
public static Response createResponseUsingStreaming() throws IOException {
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = report.generateStreamingExcelReport(100);
    StreamingOutput outputStream = workbook::write;
    final String contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(outputStream);
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test");
    responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Type", contentType);
    Response response = responseBuilder.build();
    if (null != workbook) {
        workbook.dispose();
        workbook.close();
    }
    return response;
}

public SXSSFWorkbook generateStreamingExcelReport(int rowAccessWindowSize) {
    List<List<String>> rows = createRawData();
    SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(rowAccessWindowSize);

    createExcelSummaryPage(sxssfWorkbook);
    createExcelDetailPage(rows, sxssfWorkbook);

    return sxssfWorkbook;
}
```

OPCPackage is set when creating a new SXSSFWorkbook, wondering where this is getting set to null.

```
public final void write(OutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    OPCPackage p = getPackage();
    if(p == null) {
        throw new IOException("Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already");
    }

    //force all children to commit their changes into the underlying OOXML Package
    // TODO Shouldn't they be committing to the new one instead?
    Set<PackagePart> context = new HashSet<>();
    onSave(context);
    context.clear();

    //save extended and custom properties
    getProperties().commit();

    p.save(stream);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `createExcelSummaryPage` or `createExcelDetailPage` are closing the workbook? Else, what exactly is `Response` and `Response.ResponseBuilder`? If those are asynchronous, then the workbook may be closed already when `responseBuilder.build()` invokes `workbook::write`.

Comment: No, createExcelSummaryPage or createExcelDetailPage are not closing the workbook. I'm using REST APIs to download the report and Response and Response.ResponseBuilder are javax libs that I'm using to build my response.

Comment: So `Response` and `Response.ResponseBuilder` are `javax.ws.rs.core.*`-classes? Then I would suggest tagging `java-ee` to attract `Java EE` users to this question. I cannot help then as I am not using `Java EE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work with `XSSFWorkbook` you should be able to work with `SXSSFWorkbook` using your `XSSFWorkbook`.

Here is a simple working example:

```
public void createExcelFileUsingSXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook wb) {

    SXSSFWorkbook wbSXSSF = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb);

    try {
        Path path = Files.createFile(Path.of("test.xlsx"));
        try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(path)) {
            wbSXSSF.write(outputStream);
            wbSXSSF.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this as below

```
outputStream = outputStream1 -> {
            sxssfWorkbook.write(outputStream1);
            sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
            sxssfWorkbook.close();
        };
```

The workbook was being written into on `responseBuilder.build()` so I had to bake write(), dispose(), and close() into the outputstream for this to work